# Swift difference between Int() and toInt()

Tags: swift

I need simple explanation why I use `toInt()` for converting a string to a integer.

When do I need to use `Int(variable)` instead of `variable.toInt()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift's `Int` has no constructors which accept a `String`.

Any time you want to convert a `String` to an `Int`, you *must* use `variable.toInt()`.

You can only use `Int(variable)` if `variable`'s type is in the following list:

- `Int`
- `UInt8`
- `Int8`
- `UInt16`
- `Int16`
- `UInt32`
- `Int32`
- `UInt64`
- `Int64`
- `UInt`
- `Float`
- `Double`
- `Float80`
- Any other type you write a custom `Int` `extension` for and add a custom `init` for.

For any other type, you must use an available `toInt()` method if it exists, or write your own.

The primary difference between stuff on this list and stuff not on this list is that for the most part, `Int` can accurately-ish represent everything that's in this list.  A [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) is not necessary for any of these types.

When trying to convert `"Hello World!"` to an `Int` however, what should we return?  `String`'s `toInt()` returns `nil` because `String`'s `toInt()`'s return type is `Int?` (an `Int` optional).  To do the same in an `init`, the `init` must be failable (I've posted an example at the bottom of the answer).

However, if you were to implement a struct `Rational` to represent rational fraction numbers, it might make sense to extend `Int` to include a constructor that accepts a `Rational` number:

```
extension Int {
    init(_ value: Rational) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

---

Here's a list of the available constructors for `Int` (the cases in which you can use `Int(variable)`:

```
/// A 64-bit signed integer value
/// type.
struct Int : SignedIntegerType {
    /// Create an instance initialized to zero.
    init()
    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    init(_ value: Int)    
    /// Creates an integer from its big-endian representation, changing the
    /// byte order if necessary.
    init(bigEndian value: Int)

    /// Creates an integer from its little-endian representation, changing the
    /// byte order if necessary.
    init(littleEndian value: Int)
    init(_builtinIntegerLiteral value: Builtin.Int2048)

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    init(integerLiteral value: Int)
}
```

```
extension Int {
    init(_ v: UInt8)
    init(_ v: Int8)
    init(_ v: UInt16)
    init(_ v: Int16)
    init(_ v: UInt32)
    init(_ v: Int32)
    init(_ v: UInt64)

    /// Construct a `Int` having the same bitwise representation as
    /// the least significant bits of the provided bit pattern.
    ///
    /// No range or overflow checking occurs.
    init(truncatingBitPattern: UInt64)
    init(_ v: Int64)

    /// Construct a `Int` having the same bitwise representation as
    /// the least significant bits of the provided bit pattern.
    ///
    /// No range or overflow checking occurs.
    init(truncatingBitPattern: Int64)
    init(_ v: UInt)

    /// Construct a `Int` having the same memory representation as
    /// the `UInt` `bitPattern`.  No range or overflow checking
    /// occurs, and the resulting `Int` may not have the same numeric
    /// value as `bitPattern`--it is only guaranteed to use the same
    /// pattern of bits.
    init(bitPattern: UInt)
}
```

```
extension Int {
    /// Construct an instance that approximates `other`.
    init(_ other: Float)
    /// Construct an instance that approximates `other`.
    init(_ other: Double)
    /// Construct an instance that approximates `other`.
    init(_ other: Float80)
}
```

(You can get to this list by typing `Int(0)` somewhere in Swift, right-clicking, and clicking "Jump to Definition".)

And notice, that not *all* of these are simply `Int(variable)`, some of them must be used like `Int(littleEndian:variable)` for example.

The only way you could use `Int(variable)` where `variable` is a `String` would be to add your own extension to `Int`:

```
extension Int {
    init?(_ s: String) {
        if let i = s.ToInt() {
            init(i)
        } else {
            init(0)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd recommend just sticking with `variable.ToInt()`.

Answer (score 3):

`Int(variable)` is a constructor and it has a set of types which you can use to create an `Int` variable.

`.toInt()` is like an extension that can be applied to any datatype (that supports that extension) and the datatype does not need to be one of the types supported by the Int constructor.  If a datatype knows how to converts to itself to `Int`, it can extend its functionality with the `toInt()` function.

Comment: You can always write an `Int` extension to add a constructor for any type also.